# Is this a portable way to use PHP include?

Tags: php, php-include

I'm making a website and I want to echo out some things to each page using PHP.

The simple way: `include ('menu.php');` doesn't work, i get this:

**Warning:** include(menu.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in **/home/folder/public_html/sitename.com/resources/page/index.php on line 82**

**Warning:** include(menu.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in **/home/folder/public_html/sitename.com/resources/page/index.php on line 82**

**Warning:** include(): Failed opening 'menu.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in **/home/folder/public_html/sitename.com/resources/page/index.php on line 82**

***This is the method in question*** which works: `include(dirname(__FILE__).'../../../menu.php');`

This was my previous method which worked but isn't portable: `chdir('/home/folder/public_html/sitename.com'); include 'menu.php';`

Comment: `include(dirname(__FILE__).'../../../menu.php');` looks fine, although you probably want to use `[..] . '/../../ [..]` to make sure you're not missing a `/` (double `/` like `//` are fine and better than missing one) ... I'm not entirely sure what the question is here?

Comment: My question was whether `include(dirname(__FILE__).'../../../menu.php');` is portable, if i decide to switch web hosts for example. And do you want me to insert `[..] . '/../../ [..]` in place of `.'../../../`? Excuse me if that's dumb, im new to programming.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you're looking for a way to not have to specify the full path every time.  You could use [set_include_path](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php).  Something like:

```
set_include_path(
    get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR .
    realpath(__DIR__ . '/../../../')
);

include('menu.php');
```

PHP will then search that directory whenever `include` is called.  If you use `set_include_path` just once in your main or top-level script, you can then call `include` without the full path in every other script.

I prefer to use relative paths directly in `include` instead of changing the search path.  I think it makes your code easier to follow.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but it gives me this : `Fatal error: Call to undefined function real_path() in /home/folder/public_html/sitename.com/resources/page/index.php on line 87` My main concern is having to rename the paths on each page if I ever switch hosts. @Matt

Comment: Fixed a type-o calling realpath. Also adding a little more context to my answer.